# React component library creation and usage

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a React component (react 16.0.0) library and I already tried babel, webpack and rollup.
package.json scripts and dependencies block:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "build2": "babel src --out-dir lib --delete-dir-on-start",
    "clean": "rm -f package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules",
    "build-publish": "npm run build && npm publish",
    "build3": "rm -rf lib && rollup -c"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.3.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "jsdom": "13.2.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.29.4",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^11.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^7.1.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.0",
    "rollup": "^2.10.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.23.9"
  }
```

rollup.config.js:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import packageJson from './package.json'

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: [
        {
            file: packageJson.main,
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true,
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            // This was required to fix some random errors while building
            namedExports: {
                'react-is': ['isForwardRef', 'isValidElementType'],
            },
        }),
        // "...locates modules using the Node resolution algorithm"
        resolve(),
        // Do Babel transpilation
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            babelHelpers: 'bundled',
        })
    ],
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("lib"),
        filename: "index.js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        react: "react"
    }
};
```

example functions which i want to use:

src/components/Sample.js:

```
import React from "react";

export function Sample({id, text}) {
    return <div id={id}>{test}</div>
}
```

src/components/Sample2.js:

```
import React from "react";

export function Sample2({id, text, children}) {
    return <div id={id}>
{test}
{children}
</div>
}
```

src/index.js:

```
export {Sample} from "./components/Sample";
export {Sample2} from "./components/Sample2";
```

1. case: If .npmignore contains "src" folder:
   After build and publish, if I want to use in my other project intellij not found the component however if I write the import by hand it works but not shows the attributes (such as "id").
2. case: If .npmignore NOT contains "src" folder:
   After build and publish, if I want to use in my other project intellij found the component but the src folder and it's not working because i get "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled" error. If I remove from the import the src ending it works but after that I can't see the attributes as the first case